# Is there a better way to say "The second most popular response was ..."

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-usage

The context for this question is that we administered a survey and the results are part of a reflection blog post.

The number one response was bug-free code, and we think this is ...

The second most popular response was clean code, and we think yadda yadda ...

The phrase "the second most popular response" seems clunky. The word "secondarily" comes to mind, but this only replaces "the second".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with *second most*.  I would not replace with *secondarily*, because it tends to convey a sense of *in addition* rather than *second by rank*.

You could say something like *next most popular response*, but it's not really an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already begun your list of responses with "The number one response..." you could then go on with "Second was clean code..."